# Why is the key idea behind OOP polymorphism?

Tags: oop, polymorphism

In the book C++ Primer, the author wrote: "The key idea behind OOP is polymorphism". I am not sure I understand what the author meant. What about other important stuff: Abstract, Inheritance, etc.
Can anyone elaborate on that, please?

Edit:
 I do not ask "What is polymorphism". I am asking "Why polymorphism is the key behind OOP"? Why not inheritance is the key?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: Maybe because you don't need inheritance to do OOP. Look at mixins & traits

Comment: Wikipedia disagrees with you: "Mixins are synonymous with abstract base classes. Inheriting from a mixin is not a form of specialization".  Would you care to refute this?

Comment: And this thesis on traits says: "t traits, a simple compositional model that extends single inheritance".  Raynos, would you like to explain?  http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/phd/schaerli-phd.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it's *the* key to OOP.  That's just someone's opinion.

I think there are *four* keys: abstract data types, encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism.  They belong together.

Each idea depends on the previous ones.  ADT is the only one that stands on its own.  Encapsulation needs ADT.  Polymorphism requires inheritance.

Polymorphism helps to eliminate `if`, `switch`, and `case` statements.  You don't have to write code to figure out what to do based on object type; the virtual table simply calls the right method for you behind the scenes.

Comment: polymorphism doesn't need inheritance :\

Comment: Can you elaborate on that Raynos ?

Comment: Yes, please elaborate.  I always thought that polymorphism required a base static type in order to pick out the polymorphic type at runtime.  If you've voted this answer down, either explain or rescind the down vote.

Comment: @duffymo - What about [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) and [ad-hoc polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad-hoc_polymorphism)? Those flavors of polymorphism do not seem to require a base static type.

Answer (score 1):

The Author may be saying this because :

1. When class B inherits from A then class B can be typecasted to A ----> Which is also called as polymorohism. So Inheritance directly allows polymorphism.
2. When A implements interface I*something* then A can rome around as I*something* which is also called as polymorphism. So Interfaces makes polymorphism come true.
3. Abstract : Abstract class is just another class which cannt be instantiated and act as base class (generally). Non abstract Child classes can be type casted to Abstract class and hence polymorphism.

So infact its seen that most concept of OOP can be seen as polymorphism and due to this Author might have said that.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's the idea of creating objects (with their fields, methods, etc) which can have more than one form - derived (abstract) classes, implemented interfaces and so on.

And you would have had your answer in few seconds only, if you would've had asked google, wikipedia and so on, first ;)

Comment: No, I did not ask "What is polymorphism". I was asking "Why polymorphism is the key behind OOP"? Why not inheritance is the key?

Comment: Maybe you should make sure first you understand what Polymorphism is. Inheritance is one of the key concepts behind "polymorphism"...